# Setting up a PXE Server with Plop Boot Manager on Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp, ethernet-port

I have a computer that won't boot off CD/DVD or USB (even tho it's supposed to). Since it can boot from the network, I want to setup a PXE server on my Pi that will load Plop Boot Manager so I can boot from CD or USB from there. I tried [this](http://www.nightowlconsulting.com/raspberry-pi-pxe-server/) tutorial on Raspbian but it didn't work. Something about how it couldn't find a DHCP or proxyDHCP request. Also its not for Plop Boot Manager. Can someone please help me get this working or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script that sets it up for you.

https://github.com/xor-function/plop-pxe-server

Copy it to your rpi using "git clone".

Go over it to understand what's it doing and the
different boot options it's providing.

If you feel you can make the script better, have at it.